# Can an attacker exploit my /etc/machine-id?

Tags: linux, uuid, dbus

I am writing software that needs to uniquely identify multiple different machines. I was planning on using /etc/machine-id to do this.

While reading the [docs](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/machine-id.html) for machine-id, I stumbled upon this passage:

> This ID uniquely identifies the host. It should be considered "confidential", and must not be exposed in untrusted environments, in particular on the network. If a stable unique identifier that is tied to the machine is needed for some application, the machine ID or any part of it must not be used directly. Instead the machine ID should be hashed with a cryptographic, keyed hash function, using a fixed, application-specific key.

Is this really the case? If so, what could an attacker actually exploit using the machine-id? I don't know much about d-bus, but I was under the impression that it's only for IPC, and therefore I'm not sure why it would really matter if a remote attacker knew the machine-id. I was planning on sending / storing these unencrypted, but would rather not if it's going to be a security issue.

**Edit:** This question was answered [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1214704/can-an-attacker-exploit-my-etc-machine-id) by someone familiar with the issue. Basically, the recommendation in the manpage is just for privacy reasons, not due to any actual security issues.

Comment: I'd definitely move it to http://security.stackexchange.com, but there's no close/flag for that, so... have an upvote. It seems to be popular anyway :)

Comment: @KeyWeeUsr oops... I've had problems in the past with figuring out whether something belongs in a different stack exchange or if tags are sufficient. If a moderator can / thinks it's a good idea to move this to somewhere else feel free!

Comment: Why not just hash the number? You could use `sd_id128_get_machine_app_specific` with an identifier built into your program instead.

Comment: +1 for hashing the machine ID. I think the security concerns here are mostly about privacy and tracking, but it’s possible that some system components use the machine ID as an authentication cookie.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, `sd_id128_get_machine_app_specific` looks like exactly what I need. However, I would still like a concrete answer on whether this is a real security concern or just one of privacy. As suggested by the people who flagged this question, I'm going to ask it again on Super User!